# tcpdf: add some space after writeHTML

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I write some lines in TCPDF with

```
$this->writeHTML('<p>blabla</p>', true, 0, true, true);
$this->writeHTML('<p>blabla</p>', true, 0, true, true);
```

What can I do to add some space between the two blocks? I tried

```
$this->writeHTML('<p style="margin-bottom:10px">blabla</p>', true, 0, true, true);
$this->writeHTML('<p>blabla</p>', true, 0, true, true);
```

but as I read later TCPDF can not translate margin-bottom. I could use Cells instead but I think then I would have to calculate their heights and so on to put them on the correct position, right?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can add in the end of the first <p> a <br />

Comment: Ah, yes forgot to mention - I tried that as well, but then the space is huge. I also tried to change font-size of the br via css, but it's not translated.

Comment: Of course, in CSS, you can't change size of br. You can try to put <style="margin:0 0 10 0;" >